# Order by custome value in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I Have this data:

```
id      meta_key   meta_value
1       d_t_w      4 weeks
2       d_t_w      2 Days
3       d_t_w      3 Weeks
4       d_t_w      4 Days
5       d_t_w      1 Week
```

WP query:

```
$query['orderby'] = 'd_t_w'; 
$query['order'] = ASC;  
$query = new WP_Query($query);
```

The Result:

```
  id      meta_key   meta_value
  5       d_t_w      1 Week 
  2       d_t_w      2 Days   
  3       d_t_w      3 Weeks  
  4       d_t_w      4 Days
  1       d_t_w      4 weeks
```

but what i expected:

```
id      meta_key   meta_value
2       d_t_w      2 Days
4       d_t_w      4 Days
5       d_t_w      1 Week
3       d_t_w      3 Weeks
1       d_t_w      4 weeks
```

How can apply order by on custom value like on (1 day, 2 days, 3 days, ..., 3 weeks, 4 weeks)

Answer (score 1):

if in you table `meta_value` suffix are same like weeks,days you can use this approach

```
SELECT meta_value,
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_value,' weeks','00'),' week','00'),' Days','0'),' Day','0'
    ) as odr 
 FROM `product` 
 ORDER by CAST(odr AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

in raw query language (wordpress indipendent), you can extract your field and calculate days of the string to order the query

like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT '1 Week' as c
    UNION ALL SELECT '2 Days'
    UNION ALL SELECT '3 Days'
    UNION ALL SELECT '3 Weeks'
    UNION ALL SELECT '1 Day'
    ) as t
ORDER BY TRIM(SUBSTR(t.c, 1, LOCATE(' ', t.c))) *
    IF(TRIM(SUBSTR(LOWER(t.c), LOCATE(' ', t.c))) = 'week', 7,
        IF(TRIM(SUBSTR(LOWER(t.c),LOCATE(' ', t.c))) = 'weeks', 7,
            IF(TRIM(SUBSTR(LOWER(t.c), LOCATE(' ', t.c))) = 'day', 1,
                IF(TRIM(SUBSTR(LOWER(t.c), LOCATE(' ', t.c))) = 'days', 1,
                    1)))) ASC;
```

Comment: I want it in wp_query please.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
$args = array(
'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
'meta_key'  => 'meta_value',
'order'     => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Reference web-page:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: this is not my issue, my issue is to order d_t_w and this field is string and i need to order by it as time like: 5 days before 2 weed, but if we order it as string 2 weeks will be before 5 days and this is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You can query using normal date/time order_by ASC/DESC and then convert meta value into d_t_w.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding Filter:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'deliver_to_weeks', 11, 2 );
    function deliver_to_weeks( $orderBy, $query ) {  

        $orderBy = str_ireplace('wp_postmeta.meta_value', "field(wp_postmeta.meta_value, '1 Day', '2 Days', '3 Days', '4 Days', '5 Days' , '1 Week', '2 Weeks', '3 Weeks', '4 Weeks')", $orderBy);
        return $orderBy;
    }
```